# Coral model returns corrupted data until the result is freed by python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

We are using the coral stick with a custom network we created (based on vgg as the backbone).
The edge-tpu version we're using is 2.11

The network returns 2 outputs: shape 1*12*12*65 and 1*12*12*256.
We are calling the network like this from python:

```
def _run_net(self, crop : np.ndarray):

    orig_w = crop.shape[1]
    orig_h = crop.shape[0]

    if orig_w != WIDTH or orig_h != HEIGHT:
        crop = cv2.resize(crop, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    image = crop.reshape(1, HEIGHT, WIDTH, 1)


    all_data = self.engine.RunInference(image.flatten())[1]
    tensor_sizes = self.engine.get_all_output_tensors_sizes()
    num_points = int(math.sqrt(tensor_sizes[0] / 65))
    raw_points = all_data[:tensor_sizes[0]]
    raw_points = raw_points.reshape((1, num_points, num_points, 65))
    raw_descriptors = all_data[tensor_sizes[0]:]
    raw_descriptors = raw_descriptors.reshape((1, num_points, num_points, 256))
    #Imprtant Note! the copy of raw points and desc here is a must, because as long as memory is held the net always return
    #the same results!!! this seems to be a bug in coral

    return (raw_points, raw_descriptors, orig_w, orig_h) #does not work

    #return (np.copy(raw_points), np.copy(raw_descriptors), orig_w, orig_h) #works ok!
```

And it seems until python calls gc on raw_points and raw_descriptors
each call to the same net (or even a new instance of the engine)
will result in the same output.

Comment: Are you using the edgetpu basic engine? Because it return a reference instead of copy, this is similar to this issue:
https://github.com/google-coral/project-teachable/issues/7

Comment: @NamVu, yes that is indeed the same issue and that's why we also use copy of the result. This means though, that the network can't be run in parallel on the stick, right?

Comment: You are correct, you shouldn't try to run anything parallel on a single stick.

Comment: Here a reference demo script where one of the function will run the 2 models on a single edgetpu:
https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/blob/master/examples/two_models_inference.py#L55

P.S. In the same script, there's another function that allows threadings but with 2 tpus

Comment: AFAIK, the linux driver doesn't supports having multiple processes accessing the same usb device at the same time :/

Comment: @NamVu, What about multiple threads accessing the same model or different models concurrently? at least with the detection API it seems to work and increase performance, though maybe the results are wrong, not sure

Comment: not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly, but accessing the same model on multiple threads should be okay. Essentially, you are just doing a read on the model concurrently; as long as you're creating a new engine object for each model.
The issue would be if you try to run inference on the same device at the same time with multiple processes.